# Is there a flaw in whole disk encryption vs volume or folder encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, disk-encryption

My company just implemented whole disk encryption on all laptops ([Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/endpoint-encryption/data-sheets-white-papers)) and the concept seems flawed.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I have known file in plain text and that same file in encrypted text, it possible to use that information to find the key for decryption.

If there is a better stack to ask this question on, please let me know and I'll repost.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Modern cryptography doesn't allow an attacker to learn the key given (plaintext, ciphertext) pairs. This is a "known plaintext" attack.